# How do you assign a variable amount of arguments in method definition?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, definition, args

I have a method that takes an index as the first argument and a variable amount of other arguments. I call this method multiple times in my code, passing it a range of 2-4 additional arguments, these arguments are passed to `cells`.

My issue is, for instances when I only need to pass 2 or 3 arguments, the last `cells` goes unassigned

```
def get_count(index,*args)
  if index == index
    live_count = 0
    if cells[args1].alive?
      live_count += 1
    end
    if cells[args2].alive?
      live_count += 1
    end
    if cells[args3].alive?
      live_count += 1
    end
    if cells[args4].alive?
      live_count += 1
    end
    return live_count
   end
  end
```

Is there an elegant way to pass only the amount of arguments I need without breaking this?

Edit:
I'm calling this method multiple times in an each block

```
    cells.each_with_index do |cell, index|
      get_count(0,1,5,6)
      rules(cell, get_count(0,1,5,6))

      get_count(1,0,2,5,6)
      rules(cell, get_count(1,0,2,5,6))
```

What it's doing is getting tally on each iteration and executing a function defined in `rules`. The tally resets upon each iteration.

What this is doing is looking at a 2d array of objects

```
[[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],
[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]]
```

At each index, it performs count on a specific set of other indexes. example, at index 0, it looks at index 1,5, and 6. It then executes the rules function and proceeds to do the same thing at the next index.

Comment: What do you check with `if index == index`, are you missing an `@` or do you call this recursively and removed the code?

Comment: this is nested in an each block. depending on the index, cells have different values. For example, at index 0, I'm checking if cells at 1, 5, and a 6 are alive; at index 1, I'm checking if cells at 0, 2, 5, 6 an 7 are alive.

Comment: @kel.o what's the purpose of `index`? Within your `get_count` method, `index` isn't used (aside from `index == index` which is always `true`)

Comment: What is `cells`? It does not appear to be an array or hash (or proc) as it is not passed as an argument to `get_count`, or a method.

Comment: cells is an array.

Comment: cells is a method that returns an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would iterate through the `args`, this way you only check what is actually given.

```
def get_count(index, *args)
  return unless index == index
  args.count { |arg| cells[arg].alive? }
end
```

Note that `index == index` is always `true`, so I'm not sure why that's in there.

---

From you edit I assume that you want to evaluate the passed `index` against the `index` variable at the point where you invoke `get_count`. This can be done in multiple ways. I personally would keep iteration details in the iteration block. This also keeps the method `get_count` cleaner.

```
def get_count(*args)
  args.count { |arg| cells[arg].alive? }
end

cells.each_with_index do |cell, index|
  rules(cell, get_count(1,5,6)) if index == 0
  rules(cell, get_count(0,2,5,6)) if index == 1
end
```

Comment: this is nested in an each block; depending on the index, cells have different values. For example, at index 0, I'm checking if cells at 1, 5, and a 6 are alive and tallying up the count; at index 1, I'm checking if cells at 0, 2, 5, 6 an 7 are alive.

Should I remove the index==index line from the method and place it outside of the method, something like , for index 0, get_count(1,5,6). for index 1, get_count(0,2,5,6,7) ?

Comment: You shouldn't nest method definitions inside blocks, unless they are dynamic. Then you'd use the `define_method` method. I'm not entirely sure what you're producing here. Regardless both `index`s refer to the method argument `index`, not to the outer `index`.

Comment: sorry, I should've been more clear. The method definition isnt nested in the block. I'm calling the method in a block mutiple times. I'm doing a new tally for each index. ie. for index 0, perform this tally. for index 1, perform this tally.for index 2 perform this tally. I would change the contents of my original post, but that would likely change the scope of this question.

Comment: I edited the OP to clarify... a bit more context; this is my take on Conways game of life.

Comment: @kel.o If you're looking for an full example of the game of life. I've created a full working version [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/209723/176723) some time ago.

Comment: the latter answer is very clean and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: please edit the get_count params in line 6 of your last solution, it looks like you forgot to remove the first argument `0` that we were previously assigning to the index

Comment: I haven't been able to understand the question, largely because I don't see how `cells` is visible within the method `get_count`. It's can't be a method, proc, array or hash. What is it?

Comment: @CarySwoveland My guess is that it's a method that returns some sort of array or hash.